# Why is an Async Method Taking 30x Longer to Run in my VSTO Add-in

Tags: c#, com, vsto, office-interop, ms-project

I have an MS Project VSTO add-in I'm working on. I created a WPF form and I want to click a button and show a indeterminate progress bar on the UI while a method runs. I was able to achieve this by wrapping the method in a Task.Run(), the only problem is running the method asynchronously seems to be about 30 times slower than running it normally. The method I'm calling interacts with objects from the Office.Interop.MSProject library, so I'm not sure if this is an Office or COM thing that's causing my performance woes.

```
private async void ButtonClickMethod()
{
    var tar = await RunTraceAnalysisAsync(); 
    // doing this takes ~30 times longer to run than just calling traceToolsController.RunTraceAnalysis() normally
}

private Task<TraceAnalysisResult> RunTraceAnalysisAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(() => { return traceToolsController.RunTraceAnalysis(); });
}
```

Comment: What does the code for `RunTraceAnalysisAsync()` look like?

Comment: I included it in the code snippet. Are you wanting to know what the code for `tracetoolsController.RunTraceAnalysis()` looks like?

Comment: I'm more interested in `RunTraceAnalysisAsync()`.  `RunTraceAnalysis` already works.

Comment: `RunTraceAnalysisAsync()` just puts `tracetoolsController.RunTraceAnalysis()` in a `Task.Run()` wrapper

Comment: FWIW the way I've solved the progress bar in VSTO add-ins is that I have a progress bar form that has a call forwarder class that uses Type.InvokeMember to call the specific method. So all code that uses the progress bar is initiated by showing that form and passing the name of the function to call. The call forwarder is where the actual code is called and then that function can update the progress bar while its code is running. There is no degradation in performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, most Office apps marshal calls to its object model methods back to the main thread, which is, of course, expensive. Outlook, for one, raises an exception when its detects its methods are used from a secondary thread inside the outlook.exe process.

Try to batch all object model calls to run on the main thread (you can use `Dispatcher` for that).

Comment: Hmm, no wonder Office Interop is always so slow.